# add column group below previous column group SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to move a column group below another column group?

For example, I have report that shows the schedule for a week. The column groups are Day, Date, and Time Range. So the report should show as

**Saturday

21-APR

09:00 - 12:00**

Details here

**13:00 - 14:00**

Details here

right now it  shows the two time range groups side by side.

Comment: You need to put the time range into a row group, you can still display it in your column but it must be grouped in rows. So yo column groups would be Day/Date and Row Group Time Range and details. If this is unclear, post some sample data and expected output and I'll put something together.

Comment: I have tried this approach, however the next column shows gaps if there is no detail for that particular time range. So in the example I have mentioned above, for the next day (Sunday) if there is no detail for the time range of 09:00 - 12:00, the detail shows blank for sunday. What is required is for the detail for the time range (i.e. 08:00- 09:00) of Sunday to show on the same line as the previous day. That's why the time range needs to show on the top(column).

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I'll add an answer below.

Comment: Zugi, can you hide the columns dynamically using an expression for the display/hide property on the columns?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is to use a sub report.

The subreport would take a single day as a parameter and if you have any row grouping, it would also have to accept a parameter to identify which row it belongs to.

The subreport should be built so that passing it a single day shows all the time ranges stacked with details. To do this, add a parent row grouping to details group, grouped by the Time Range field.

In your main report, your row grouping (if any), would remain the same, just make sure it does not group by any of the time related data that will appear in the columns.

Set the Column grouping to Day/Date and insert your subreport into the data cell area of the matrix.

If any of this is unclear please post some sample data and sketch up the required output so I can put together a more detailed answer.